# Django admin: Second level ordering in list_display

Tags: sorting, django-models, django-admin

While showing a model in Django's admin's list_display, I'd like to sort first by one column, then by another.
Here's an example model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    the_date = models.DateField()
```

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the "ordering" attribute of an admin class.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/

Edit: My previous answer is incorrect. According to the documentation above, Django only honors the first entry in the tuple. There is/was [a ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/389) to resolve this that went nowhere. There are various other proposed solutions that I also tried, but none of them seemed to work with my version of Django.

However, I came back to this problem today as part of a project and finally found something that worked for me. My solution was based upon [this Django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2110/), and I will post the snippet code here for completeness.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
from tunes.models import Song

class SpecialOrderingChangeList(ChangeList):
    def apply_special_ordering(self, queryset):
        order_type, order_by = [self.params.get(param, None) for param in ('ot', 'o')]
        special_ordering = self.model_admin.special_ordering
        if special_ordering and order_type and order_by:
            try:
                order_field = self.list_display[int(order_by)]
                ordering = special_ordering[order_field]
                if order_type == 'desc':
                    ordering = ['-' + field for field in ordering]
                queryset = queryset.order_by(*ordering)
            except IndexError:
                return queryset
            except KeyError:
                return queryset
        return queryset

    def get_query_set(self):
        queryset = super(SpecialOrderingChangeList, self).get_query_set()
        queryset = self.apply_special_ordering(queryset)
        return queryset

class SongAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'time', 'artist', 'album', 'track', 'total_tracks']
    special_ordering = {'artist': ('artist', 'album', 'track'), 'album': ('album', 'track')}

    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return SpecialOrderingChangeList

admin.site.register(Song, SongAdmin)
```

Comment: Nope. Django documentation says on ordering: "Django will only honor the first element in the list/tuple; any others will be ignored."

Comment: Well-spotted. Funny, I have used this lots of times assuming that because it was a tuple, it was ordering by all the columns. I guess I've never noticed that it didn't! In that case, I think we would have to override the queryset() method of the model's ModelAdmin to change the sort order.

Comment: I tried that too and it didn't help. If you happen to succeed in this direction, could you please post your code?

Comment: Thanks; this essentially worked; though I cut down on the answer a bit (and posted as a different answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is based on bogeyman Apr 1 edited answer, but broken down to the essential feature.

In my models.py define `ordering` in the models `Meta` as usual:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    the_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('the_date', 'name') # sort by date then name.
```

Then in admin.py subclass `ChangeList`, but force the query_set to ultimately be sorted by the ordering specified in the Meta of the model.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList


class SpecialOrderingChangeList(ChangeList):
    def get_query_set(self):
        queryset = super(SpecialOrderingChangeList, self).get_query_set()
        return queryset.order_by(*self.model._meta.ordering)

class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return SpecialOrderingChangeList

admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)
```

If you'd rather define the ordering in the ModelAdmin; you could do that as well; just change `return queryset.order_by(*self.model._meta.ordering)` to `return queryset.order_by(*self.model_admin.ordering)` and add a list defining `ordering = ['the_date', 'name']` in `CustomerAdmin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Django trunk rather than 1.3

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

> New in Django Development version.
>
> If you need to specify a dynamic
>   order (for example depending on user or language) you can implement a
>   get_ordering() method.
>
> Changed in Django Development version.
>
> Django honors all elements in
>   the list/tuple; before 1.4, only the first was respected.